# Using the Graph API does not get notifications (PHP SDK)

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-php-sdk

I have followed the instructions to get access_token and use the graph API to get notifications. My PHP code is like:

```
echo "get limit 3 notifications";

$args = array(
 'limit' => '3',
 'access_token' => 'mytoken....'
 );

 $data = $facebook->api('/my_facebook_id/notifications','GET',$args);

 $arrays = $data['data'];

 echo "count size: ".count($arrays).;

 print_r($arrays);

 echo "<br/><br/>";
```

However, I always get zero notifications. Although, when I logged in, there is two new notifications in my home page.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Also, I want to get messages using the graph API but seems there is no 
"http://graph.facebook.com/my_facebook_id/messages/"

Regarding to the notifications and messages, they are all in the top left bar, following friends requests.

I wonder if someone has experienced with this and can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure token is correct.
2. Try it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fnotifications)
3. Change /my_facebook_id/ to /me/
4. Use try{}catch{}

---

```
try{
 echo "get limit 3 notifications";

 $args = array(
 'limit' => '3',
 'access_token' => 'mytoken....'
 );

 $data = $facebook->api('/my_facebook_id/notifications','GET',$args);

 $arrays = $data['data'];

 echo "count size: ".count($arrays).;

 print_r($arrays);

 echo "<br/><br/>";
}
catch (Exception $e){
   print_r($e); // this will give you errors thrown
}
```